# Is it possible to change scoreboard number color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Just curious to see if it´s possible to change the number that displays the score of an objective, i know you can change the player color with teams but not the score color.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with commands. Maybe a resource pack could change the colour for all numbers, but maybe not even that.